# How to output return code in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to call a custom shell script through `sh`:

```
/bin/sh -c 'myscript.sh` >log.txt 2>&1 & echo $!
```

Output of this command is a PID of a created background process. I want to instruct `/bin/sh` to save return code of `myscript.sh` to some file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
(/bin/sh -c "myscript.sh" >log.txt 2>&1 ; echo $? >somefile) & echo $!
```

Answer (score 39):

```
echo $? >> /path/to/return_code
```

$? has the return code of the last statement in bash.

Comment: But not when it was put in the background. It's easy to miss the `&` in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

```
(
/bin/sh -c 'myscript.sh` >log.txt 2>&1
echo $? > some_file
) &
```