# Can't get fatal error log for my Java application

Tags: java, performance, crash

Help! I have a Java headless iterative calculation-intensive servlet running 24/7 on Unix, that a few builds ago has started crashing after about a day or so, and I can't for the LIFE of me get a crash log / dump / indicator of any kind as to why. No manner of JVM arguments, shut down hooks, etc have helped me to get any sort of log as to what might be happening. Crash is not reproducible on-command, or predictable. Happens roughly every 20-30 hours.

OS: Amazon Linux AMI

Hardware: AWS EC2 T3.medium instance (4GB mem)

JVM arguments are below

**STEPS TRIED SO FAR:**

- Tried -XX:ErrorFile JVM arg with different paths and file names, to no avail (no error file created, tried looking everywhere). Definitely no existing file that would block another one from being written.
- Tried -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError JVM arg (no dump file created, tried looking everywhere).
- Opened permissions on the application home directory to 777 so that the logs can write.
- Opened permissions on the Java home directory to 777 as well, just in case (Java directory discovered by using 'which java' command): /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.45.amzn1.x86_64
- Checked GC logs - no Full GCs around the crash, however the GC logs have always been pretty active even while stable, with YoungGen minor reclamation every 10 seconds or so. GC logs leading up to the crash show no deviation in pattern from GC logs 1 hour or 12 hours prior.
- Checked app logs - it always crashes around a flurry of OKHTTP requests, but there's also a TON of other async processing stuff happening at the same time, so it's hard to tell if its HTTP/network-related or not (could be)
- Added a shutdown hook in the app code to dump all stack traces to the app log upon exit, but nothing is ever printed during the crash (yet a simple manual 'kill PID' command proves the shutdown hook works)
- Hard to tell INSTANTANEOUS memory usage during the crash, but intermittent logs showing memory stats from a second or two before it shows an average usage of around 1.5GB (on a 2.5GB max JVM, sometimes 3GB)
- Tried several different Unix machines, with varying amounts of RAM (same issue)
- Tried fooling with JVM arg memory limit (-Xmx) to no avail

I am at my wits' end just trying to get a crash log to figure out what might be happening. Any other suggestions on what to try next?

**JVM arguments** (within start.ksh file in app home directory, executed as su):

sudo -u arbadm java -cp ${CLASSPATH} -d64 -Xms2048m -Xmx2560m -Xloggc:../log/gc_`date +%F`.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=5M -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ErrorFile=./hs_err_file_%p.log -Xss4096k -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false com.package.Main &

Comment: Check the exit code of the process. The code < 128 means the Java process has exited voluntarily, e.g. by calling `System.halt`. The code `128+N` means the process was killed by a signal `N`. E.g. 137 (SIGKILL) is often sent by the OS when a process exceeds the memory limit (or probably some other limit). The code 139 (SIGSEGV) would mean a JVM bug or a stack overflow in the native code.

Comment: @apangin How could I get the exit code (ie, log to a file somewhere)? My current bash script goes something like this: `sudo -u arbadm java package.main.Main &`, and as you can see runs as a background process (ie, the & at the end of the shell command).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810279/how-to-output-return-code-in-shell

Comment: Checking... will report back in a day or two when the program exits again

Comment: @apangin OK, got the crash again. But alas... NO exit code file was created. I even tested the script functionality by sending a `kill -9` command to the process a few times and each time exit code printed to a file, but in practice for the mysterious crash I'm experience it's not being created. Does this indicate some larger issue? I don't even know how it would be possible for it to exit in this manner... almost seems like a hardware fault to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's also a chance that bash is killed together with Java process, so no exit code printed. Do you have access to kernel logs (dmesg)? Check if there is anything suspicious out there. I also suggest to monitor physical memory usage on the server - a slow memory leak that gradually exhausts all 4GB in 20-30 hours would be my first guess.

Comment: @apangin Good to know - I just spun up a different physical machine running on a different AMI (machine image), so I've lost the log. I'll try again and report back. Regarding memory, it seems to be under control - I have records of physical memory printed to the log preceding the crash, and it's typically under 3GB used, but that doesn't rule out a sharp spike :). I'll figure out a better way to look into this as well

Comment: @apangin dmesg was unchanged since machine boot. The only /var/log/ files that changed are `cron`, `messages`, and `secure`, all of which are perfectly normal and consistent during that time (fyi - i'm not using any cron jobs). I also managed to get a JVM memory log about 100ms before the crash - `Heap: 214 MB (2376 MB max)`
`Non-Heap: 71 MB (-1 MB max)`
`Code Cache: 32 MB (240 MB max)`
`Metaspace: 35 MB (-1 MB max)`
`Compressed Class Space: 3 MB (1024 MB max)`
`PS Eden: 47 MB (793 MB max)`
`PS Survivor: 24 MB (29 MB max)`
`PS Old Gen: 142 MB (1707 MB max)`

Comment: @apangin According to the above printout, nothing seems out of line with the memory usage. I also checked the AWS memory charts for the machine itself - no spikes to speak of. I'm at a complete loss at what to try next. Based on what I've isolated so far, the only constant here seems to be my code. However, the crash appears to be so violent (ie, lack of exit code upon exit) that I can't wrap my mind around how it could be a code issue.

Comment: @apangin Well I'm an idiot - it turns out that the runtime wasn't crashing at all, but rather becoming a zombie process with no CPU usage due to a synchronization issue of my own coding, and therefore not appearing on `top` command I was using (should've used `ps grep | ef java` in the first place). Your help was actually invaluable to me in expanding the list of things that it WASN'T, and leading me to the only possible conclusion, which is that the process didn't die. Again, I'm an idiot, but I learned a lot about post-mortem crash analysis in the process, so THANK YOU!!!