# Where to find java virtual machine logs on linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I have a tomcat server running with Spring on linux. Unfortunaly it is shutting down automatically.

Now I check already a lot. In my spring logs there is nothing.

Now I want to check the jvm logs. Maybe I can find something there.

I already found the pure java command. It is located under path:

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_201/bin

But where are the logs ?  Sometimes I read it should be under /var/log/java

But under /var/log  there is no java folder in my case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What JVM logs are you talking about? Actually, it does not log anything unless you've asked it to. `hs_err_pid*.log` crash dump is generated only when JVM terminates abnormally. If an applications exits e.g. by calling `System.exit`, there will be no crash dump. See the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651010/cant-get-fatal-error-log-for-my-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

The default location (directory) of the trace and log files is:

`<user.home>/.java/deployment/log` on UNIX, Linux 
`~/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/log` on Mac OS X 
`<User Application Data Folder>\Sun\Java\Deployment\log` on Windows

Comment: I am going to cd  /root  because I am logged in as root , but there is no .java Folder . I think the dot means hidden ?

Comment: parallel to /root there would be /home/<some_user>. Try going inside and check once.

Comment: in my case under cd /home  there is no user .  I just tried   find / -name  "*hs_err_pid*"   to find possible JVM error logs , but there is not a single error log in my Linux system